# Python not displaying entire CSV file form SFTP

Tags: python, csv, paramiko

So I've connected to an SFTP server using paramiko and I'm trying to display an entire CSV file without downloading it.

```
import paramiko


host,port = 'HOST',22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))


username,password = 'LOGIN','PASS'
transport.connect(None,username,password)


sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)


listdir = sftp.listdir()


import pandas
import csv
file = sftp.open('fixed.csv')


csvreal = pandas.read_csv(file)
for row in csvreal:
    print(row)




file.close()

if sftp: sftp.close()
if transport: transport.close()
```

The CSV file has hundreds of lines, but when I run this, it only displays the first row. What am I doing wrong? No idea why this shouldn't be working properly. Please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, you neither using the csv package at all, nor pandas to its full power.

If you simply want to print the entire row as one, you could replace your loop:

```
for index, row in csvreal.iterrows():
    print(csvreal.loc[[index]].to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

In order to parse your data, you might want to take a closer look at pandas documentation and start with some tutorials. Based on your comment, your data might look something like `d`, so for starters, consider the following code snippet:

```
d = {'COURSENAME': ['french', 'spanish'], 'COURSECODE': ['F1', 'S2'], 'COMPLETION_DATE': ['2020-04-08', '2020-01-27']}
csvreal = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(csvreal)
for index, row in csvreal.iterrows():
    print('The course', row['COURSENAME'], 'was completed on', row['COMPLETION_DATE'])
```

Depending on your data, it might be useful to reset your index. Please provide more detailed information on the structure of your csv file (especially the header) for a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you! But what is df? Not sure what to replace that with

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue, works now. I do have another minor problem. It seems to be converting the entire row into one string, which I need to parse. What would be the best way to approach this? For example, one row is "COURSENAME  COURSECODE  COMPLETION_DATE  NAME". I need to read the coursenames and completion dates

Comment: I see, I see, thank you so much for the edit! Where can I read about that in particular? I've very new and have no idea what I am doing